# Discard Kafka commits for a consumer group if older than x seconds?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Lets say I have a Kafka consumer registered with `Group Id 'G'` to listen `topic stream 'T'`. It is configured in Java as follows:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);
    props.put("group.id", groupId);
    props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "60000");
    props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "2000");
    props.put("auto.commit.enable", "true");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
    return new ConsumerConfig(props);
```

Now I need to configure my consumer group to discard the offset commit if it is too old (say older than x seconds) and take the largest offset(latest). Is there any way to do that?

**Edit**: Follow up question. Is there any way to delete commit offset on demand programmatically from consumer?